# Maxima CAS Simplifying

Tags: maxima-software

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how to enter this equation into Maxima CAS so I can simplify it?

```
(8a^2 + b^5 + c^-2) / (2a^5 + b^2 + c^-1/2)^-1/6
```

Many thanks

Amanda

Comment: Be much more precise with your brackets for a start - its easy to add brackets and get a completely different formula in my CAS $$( (8a)^2 + b^5 + c^{(-2 )}) / ( (2a)^5 + b^2 + c^{(-1/2) })^{(-1/6)}$$

Comment: @Amanda: In any case, what makes you think the expression can be made simpler?

Comment: Because that's what I have been asked to do for my assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JamesArathoon already mentioned, your expression as it is now admits multiple interpretations. Also you seem to miss the second part of the *equation*.
Make sure you use parenthesis as well as the multiplication sign (`*`). If you want to use it in maxima, I'd recommend assigning it to a variable (in this case `t`). Try following:

```
t : (8*a^2 + b^5 + c^(-2))/(2*a^5 + b^2 + c^(-1/2))^(-1/6);
print(t);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02syMxN/P@/RMFKQcNCKzHOSEFbISnOFEgmx2noGmlq6msYAYVNwcJGUGFDfaAEmDbTtOYqKMrMK9Eo0bT@/x8A)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked